# Bootstrap UI Angular Accordion and Rails template must have one root element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to use the example accordion directive in my rails app but receive the following error and my browser crashes

```
Template for directive 'accordionGroup' must have exactly one root element.  
template/accordion/accordion-group.html
```

My HTML view is the same as the example accordion (shortened for readability here)

```
<div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">

  <accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
    <accordion-group heading="Static Header, initially expanded" is-open="status.isFirstOpen" is-disabled="status.isFirstDisabled">
      This content is straight in the template.
    </accordion-group>
    <accordion-group heading="{{group.title}}" ng-repeat="group in groups">
      {{group.content}}
    </accordion-group>
  </accordion>
 </div>
```

My routes:

```
angular
  .module('App', [
    'ngRoute',
    'templates',
    'ui.bootstrap'
  ])
    .when('/page', {
      templateUrl: 'page.html',
      controller: 'PageCtrl'
    })
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  });
```

I'm also using the angular template gem and not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: Could you please add your `AccordianDemoCtrl` and relevant state?

Comment: can you please setup a plunker...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar error with angular bootstrap and this was due to using

`ui-bootstrap.js` instead of `ui-bootstrap-tpls.js`

Answer (score 0):

It might be the BOM in your accordion template file causing an issue.

Open the file in a text editor that allows you to change the encoding (like Notepad++), alter the file to be UTF-8 without BOM and save. That should solve it (assuming that's the issue!).